# Unknown attribute when monetizing a field using money-rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, currency, money-rails

I have the following class and I want to `monetize` a couple of its fields using the `money-rails` gem.

```
class LineItem < ActiveRecord::Base
  monetize :unit_price_cents
  monetize :total_cents
end
```

This is how the schema looks:

```
create_table "line_items", force: :cascade do |t|                                                             
   t.integer  "invoice_id"                                                                                     
   t.float    "quantity"                                                                                       
   t.string   "unit_type"                                                                                      
   t.string   "description"                                                                                    
   t.datetime "created_at",       null: false                                                                  
   t.datetime "updated_at",       null: false
   t.integer  "unit_price_cents", null: false                                                                                                                               
   t.integer  "total_cents",      null: false                                                                  
end
```

For some reason I get `undefined method 'unit_price' for #<LineItem:0x007ffb7881eb80>`
 unless I add aliasing to the monetized fields:

```
monetize :unit_price_cents, as: :unit_price
```

Answer (score 1):

As per Money Rails gem [documentation](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails#usage), the `:as` is not necessary in this case. It should only be used if you are using another db column name, or you prefer another name for the money attribute.

In your case since your db column name is already in the format the gem expects. You only have to do

```
monetize :unit_price_cents
```

To then call `unit_price` on you LineItem instance to get the monetized object

```
@lineitem = LineItem.first
@lineitem.unit_price
```